# trying to understand node exists in binary tree (recursion func) in python

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to understand below recursion function which says whether a particular node exists in a binary tree. I did my homework and got most of the recursion part but the last return statement (return root.value == value or inleft or inright) bothers me.

can someone please help me in understanding this method?

```
    def existsInTree(self, root, value):
        if root is None:
            return False
        else:
            inleft = self.existsInTree(root.left, value)
            inright = self.existsInTree(root.right, value)
            print(inleft,inright)
            return root.value == value or inleft or inright

 example binary tree:

            10
           /  \
        11     9
```

Comment: The function returns true if THIS node has the value, OR the left node contained the value somewhere, OR the right node contained the value somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

we will first compare data of root with data of node to be searched. If the match is found, set the flag to true. Else, search the node in left subtree and then in the right subtree.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way of looking at that return statement, you can split the return statement at the `or` keyword

```
def ifRootExists(self,root, value):
 
    if (root == None):
        return False
 
    if (root.value == value):
        return True
 
    """ then recur on left sutree """
    res1 = ifrootExists(root.left, value)
    # root found, no need to look further
    if res1:
        return True
 
    """ root is not found in left,
    so recur on right subtree """
    res2 = ifrootExists(root.right, value)
 
    return res2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the result from the above function whether some node exists.

The algorithm is as follows.

1. root is None or Not. If None, get back the position which the parent function called with the value of "False".
2. Otherwise, the function continuously search based on the current node.

- inleft is a value of function "existsInTree" in which the current node's left child is the root node.
- inright is a value of function "existsInTree" in which the current node's right child is the root node.

3. Let's assume that we want to search value as called V.
   Which V exists in the tree means the current value is V or in the left tree, or in the right tree.

To summarize, inleft and inright means whether V includes or not in the subtree.